# Appending a table together with changing id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im appending a table with select and input elements on its cells, tho the value of id is changing but only for a single element on the cell.

My Javascript

```
 function deleteRow(row)
{
var i=row.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
document.getElementById('POITable').deleteRow(i);
}


 function insRow()
{
console.log( 'hi');
var x=document.getElementById('addTable');
var new_row = x.rows[1].cloneNode(true);
var len = x.rows.length;
new_row.cells[0].innerHTML = len;

var inp1 = new_row.cells[1].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
inp1.id += len;
inp1.value = '';
var inp2 = new_row.cells[2].getElementsByTagName('select')[0];
inp2.id += len;
inp2.value = '';
var inp3 = new_row.cells[2].getElementsByTagName('select')[0];
inp3.id += len;
inp3.value = '';
var inp4 = new_row.cells[3].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
inp4.id += len;
inp4.value = '';
x.appendChild( new_row );
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="POItablediv">
<input type="button" id="addPOIbutton" value="Add POIs"/><br/><br/>
<td><input type="button" id="addmorePOIbutton" value="Add More POIs" onclick="insRow()"/></td>
<table id="addTable" border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>POI</t>
        <td>Latitude</td>
        <td>timezone</td>
        <td>zzz</td>
        <td>Delete?</td>
        <td>Add Rows?</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td><input size=25 type="text" id="latbox"/></td>
        <td><select id="selectbox"><option value='am'>AM</option>
                                        <option value='pm'>PM</option> </select>
            <select id="gmtbox"><option value='gmt+'>gmt+</option>
                                        <option value='gmt-'>gmt-</option> </select>
                                    </td>
        <td><input size=25 type="text" id="zzz"></td>

    </tr>
</table>
</body>
```

I don't get a problem with the id latbox and zzz because they are the only element on their cell, but for selectbox and gmt it seems that only selectbox id is the only one that changes every time I append but not for gmtbox. How do i get to do change gmtbox?

Answer (score 1):

Because you are getting the same element for

```
var inp2 = new_row.cells[2].getElementsByTagName('select')[0];
```

and

```
var inp3 = new_row.cells[2].getElementsByTagName('select')[0];
```

2nd one needs to be

```
var inp3 = new_row.cells[2].getElementsByTagName('select')[1];
```